# How to add an item to a many-to-many relationship table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In my EF Core data model I have two table, the first table have an `ICollection` Navigation property to the second table and the second table also have an `ICollection` Navigation property to the first table.

## Data Model

```
public class MyUser
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PrivateUser> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class PrivateUser
{
    [Key]
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

When I first add a `MyUser` only with name,

```
 appuser = new MyUser
 {
      UserName = Context.User.Identity.Name
 };
 _context.MyUser.Add(appuser);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

it's adding the user to the table correctly but when I try add a `PrivateUser` with an existing `MyUser` or I try to update the existing `MyUser` it gives `NullReferenceException` from the below code.

```
PrivateUser roma = new PrivateUser() { RoomName = roomName};
try
{
    var user = new MyUser() { UserName = Context.User.Identity.Name };
    user.Rooms.Add(roma);
    _context.MyUsers.Attach(user).Property(u => u.Rooms).IsModified = true;
    roma.Users.Add(user);
    await _context.Rooms.AddAsync(roma);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I've also configured it in the ModelBuilder.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().HasMany(u => u.Rooms);
     modelBuilder.Entity<PrivateUser>().HasMany(c => c.Users);

}
```

I'm a beginner on EF Core, can somebody please explain me how I can save the fields in correct way when the both table referencing themselves.

Comment: The relationship you are explaining is called *many-to-many*, and currently requires explicit join entity and different type of the collection navigation properties. See [Relationships - Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) documentation topic.

Comment: should i change the question title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigate I found there was no problem with my Entity Model the problem was because I solved that problem on my first `Migration` by using `ModelBuilder`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().HasMany(u => u.Rooms);
   modelBuilder.Entity<PrivateUser>().HasMany(c => c.Users);
}
```

The problem was in my `try` block, see the correct code below.

```
try
{
    var user = new MyUser() { UserName = Context.User.Identity.Name };
    //here I was doing user.Rooms.Add(roma); where Romms is null
    roma.Rooms = new ICollection<PrivateUser>();
    //now we can add the room to Rooms
    user.Rooms.Add(roma);
    //and here was the below commented code from a Stackoverflow Answer
    //_context.MyUsers.Attach(user).Property(u => u.Rooms).IsModified = true;
    //we just have to use Update here;
    _context.MyUsers.Attach(user);
    _context.MyUsers.Update(user);
    roma.Users.Add(user);
    await _context.Rooms.AddAsync(roma);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Now everything fine as expected. Thanks...